# Fetch the details from database using laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to get the details from database and written  below Laravel code to fetch the details from two table using join query. But it is taking too much time while fetching the data.

Can you guys help me? So it will take minimum time to fetch the API.

```
   public function getWebsiteVisitorsDetails($businessId, $startTime, $endTime, $filterType){
        $chatBotClicked = DB::table('chatbot_website_visitor_detail')
            ->join('website_visitors_task', 'website_visitors_task.website_session_id', '=', 'chatbot_website_visitor_detail.website_session_id')
            ->where('website_visitors_task.session_task_perform' , 3)
            ->where('chatbot_website_visitor_detail.business_id', $businessId);
        if($filterType != ApiConstant::ALL_TIME){
            $chatBotClicked = $chatBotClicked->whereBetween('website_visitors_task.created_at', [$startTime, $endTime]);
        }

        $feedbackClicked = DB::table('chatbot_website_visitor_detail')
            ->join('website_visitors_task', 'website_visitors_task.website_session_id', '=', 'chatbot_website_visitor_detail.website_session_id')
            ->where('website_visitors_task.session_task_perform' , 2)
            ->where('chatbot_website_visitor_detail.business_id', $businessId);
        if($filterType != ApiConstant::ALL_TIME){
            $feedbackClicked = $feedbackClicked->whereBetween('website_visitors_task.created_at', [$startTime, $endTime]);
        }

        $firstTimeVisitor = DB::table('chatbot_website_visitor_detail')
            ->select('chatbot_website_visitor_detail.id')
            ->where('chatbot_website_visitor_detail.business_id', $businessId)
            ->where('chatbot_website_visitor_detail.from_popup_widget', 1);
        if($filterType != ApiConstant::ALL_TIME){
            $firstTimeVisitor = $firstTimeVisitor->whereBetween('chatbot_website_visitor_detail.created_at', [$startTime, $endTime]);
        }

        $returnData['chatbot_clicked'] = $chatBotClicked->count();
        $returnData['feedback_clicked'] = $feedbackClicked->count();
        $returnData['first_time_user'] = $firstTimeVisitor->count();
    }
```

Comment: Use caching? Have you set up indexes/foreign keys in your tables? How much is "_too much time_"?

Comment: No, I have not setup index but i used foreign keys. It is taking more than 40 sec to get the 80000 count.

Comment: Step 1 is to add index, otherwise any fix/change is pointless. Another tip is to use [Laravel Debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) to track slow quries.